# tempDirectory compilation configuration

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I'd like to add `<compilation tempDirectory="MyPath"/>` to the web.config of my webservice.

Is it possible to specify a relative path? or it can only take an absolute path?

Comment: Do you have solved the relative path problem? It seems absurd to not be able to set a relative path. What one should do when the site is not on your premise and the ISP doesn't tell you the absolute path of the hosted site?

Answer (score 3):

Goto to webconfig file, remove the path value only.

This usually cause when files are moved from one domain to another.

Answer (score 0):

From [tempDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s10awwz0.aspx),

> Specifies the directory to use for temporary file storage during compilation.

I think your best bet would be the absolute path; but, you can try the relative like:

```
<compilation tempDirectory="Default Web Site/YourApp"/>
```

Comment: I wanted to for the tempDirectory to be in the same as the webservice ... I tried tempDirectory = "Temp" ... and it complains about it needing to be an absolute path. :(

Answer (score 0):

temp directory is processed as follows:

```
   if ((compilationSection != null) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(compilationSection.TempDirectory))
{
    path = compilationSection.TempDirectory;
    compilationSection.GetTempDirectoryErrorInfo(out tempDirAttribName, out configFileName, out configLineNumber);
}
if (path != null)
{
    path = path.Trim();
    if (!Path.IsPathRooted(path))
    {
        path = null;
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            path = new DirectoryInfo(path).FullName;
        }
        catch
        {
            path = null;
        }
    }
    if (path == null)
    {
        throw new ConfigurationErrorsException(SR.GetString("Invalid_temp_directory", new object[] { tempDirAttribName }), configFileName, configLineNumber);
    }
```

where IsPathRooted return true if (path[0] is '\' or '/') or (path[1] is ':')

to set a relative path:

```
<compilation tempDirectory="/Default Web Site/YourApp"/>
```

Comment: As far as I cen see from testing (VS2017) and from reading the code, a path like that would be interpreted as a rooted path, meaning the `/Default Web Site/YourApp` folder would end up in the drive's root. There does not appear to be any way to specify a relative folder.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to specify a relative path, as the error message also clearly indicates.